# How do I use a method to construct and return a random phrase from another file?

Tags: java, class, methods

My assignment is to write two classes that reference the same object, each with their own set of requirements.

The first class should produce one of two results:
1. combine 1 preposition, 1 article, and 1 noun (“under the rock”)
2. combine 1 preposition, 1 article, 1 adjective, and 1 noun (“under the breezy rock”)

It should randomly pick one of these two results and output it. I'm a little green and I need advice on a place to start. Here is what I have:

```
public class PurpleRobot{
    private Vocabulary words;
    public String getPhrase();
    String PhrasePrepositions = words.getRandomPrepositions();
    return PhrasePrepositions;
    String PhraseArticle = words.getRandomArticles();
    return PhraseArticle;  
    String PhraseNoun = words.getRandomNoun();
    return PhraseNoun;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    PurpleRobot purple = new PurpleRobot();
    System.out.println(purple.getPhrasePrepositions() + purple.getPhraseArticles() + purple.getPhraseNoun() );
}
}
```

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea where to start, please have a look at this site here as it will give you some ideas: [Starting Writing a Program](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html), the key process being to break the big project down into small steps, and then solving each small step one at a time. If you're still having problems, then you might wish to consider talking to your instructor.

Comment: I think you need to [take a step back](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) because there are some pretty glaringly obvious errors all over that code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think, will be better way is create the random variable. Then define an array with your phrases, and then just get a random Integer value from 0 to 2(because array index is start with zero)